# MATLAB System Command Gives Segmentation Fault?

Tags: matlab, terminal

I am using an external solver to run simulations. I am trying to call the external solver with system(cmd) from a MATLAB script. The cmd itself runs fine with no problems from the Terminal (I'm running on OSX). However, every time the MATLAB script runs, the status is 139 - Segmentation Fault. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: It's really impossible to tell. It is an issue with your external program, not MATLAB. Do you have environment variables that the external program relies upon?

Comment: Yes, there are certain environment variables in my home directory .bash_profile

Comment: Right, so none of those are respected when you make a `system` command from MATLAB. You'll need to use `setenv` to set necessary environment variables

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue. If you post it as an "answer" I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing the `system` command this is *not* the same as running a program from the terminal since you likely have environment variables defined within your terminal session (via `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`) that are going to effect how a program is accessed and run.

If you have environment variables that you need to set for the program to run successfully, use `setenv` from within MATLAB prior to calling `system`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Matlab (R2016b), but the solution was exactly the opposite.

Instead of missing variables, `system()` defined `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which redirected to some shared libraries packaged with Matlab that didn't sit well with my program. After clearing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my script, everything worked fine. You can do that for example with this:

```
env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```